# Magento 2: Translate knockout html where "mailto:info@sitename.com" is used

Tags: javascript, translate, knockout

> In Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/content.html there is a
> "mailto:info@website.com" used.
> Now I can translate the last piece by -- ko text: $t('info@website.com') -->
> <-- /ko --> into something like "info@website.co.uk".
> **But how can I translate "mailto:info@website.com" into
> "mailto:@website.co.uk"?**
> So that I can use it for a multistore website.
> I believe it is in JS knockout: see the code below:

```
    <!-- ko ifnot: getCartParam('summary_count') -->


    <div class="c-minicart__footer__right col-8">
        <i class="icon-envelope"></i>
        <a href="mailto:info@website.com">info@website.com</a>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: This is not about `translating`, you should overwrite or directly edit the file

Comment: do you mean you want the frontend to dispaly info@website.co.uk? and yet the email value to be info@website.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use so tag:

```
<!-- ko ifnot: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
<div class="c-minicart__footer__right col-8">
        <i class="icon-envelope"></i>
        <a href="#" attr="href: $t('mailto:info@website.com')">>
                <translate args="'info@website.com'"/>
        </a>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: thanx! This works perfect! It's easy if you know it :)